# How to capture large video files with android media recorder

Tags: android, media, video-capture, android-mediarecorder

I want to capture a large video file using android media recorder. When i use the standard method by saving the file into sd card, after some time (1 hour) video capturing stopped and the camera hanged. Captured video file was also not playable since it stops during capturing. Is there any method to capture a large video file with android?